# Mysql query not giving exact records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I want the unique records against each user and product id. So my query is working fine but a small issue is, I am not getting the exact value of columns against the order id.

```
select max(o.id) as order_id, u.email,oi.product_id, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(o.paid_time), '%Y-%m-%d') as paid_times  
from `order` o 
join `users` u on u.id = o.user_id 
join order_item oi on oi.order_id = o.id 
where oi.product_id in (1212,1213)
group by u.email, oi.product_id
order by o.id desc;
```

Try - 2

```
select max(o.id) as order_id, u.email,oi.product_id, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(o.paid_time), '%Y-%m-%d') as paid_times  
from `order` o 
join `users` u on u.id = o.user_id 
join order_item oi on oi.order_id = o.id 
where oi.product_id in (1212,1213) and o.id IN (SELECT max(id) FROM `order`)
group by u.email, oi.product_id
order by o.id desc;
```

I get the max order id, which is fine. but the paid_time is not of this order id.

Current Results:

[image]

Desired Results:

[image]

Comment: You can try using self join on order table

Comment: Kindly share sample data and your desired output.

Comment: @zarruq, i have updated the question

Comment: Kindly also share sample data in text format for tables `orders`, `users` and `order_item` from which the desired output is required.

Comment: In general, if an unaggregated column appears in the SELECT then it must also appear in the GROUP BY. That said, I suspect you're after something different.

Comment: Internet etiquette prohibits me from properly expressing my thoughts on providing result sets without data sets, but see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

This is very common type of error. for this first you need to get the max order id than use it in where condition as taking max with select and others columns mysql gives you max order id and any row data which comes first not the data related to max id.

Understand below example

```
SELECT name
FROM table 
WHERE id=(
    SELECT max(id) FROM table
    )
```

above will give you data of max(id) from table

```
 SELECT name , max(id)
    FROM table
```

the above query will display Maximum id but not the matching  name

http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/sql_max.php

Comment: but it gave me only one record against the max order id. :( I just put 
`and o.id = (SELECT max(id) FROM `order` )` in the query

Comment: No bro, it doesnt work. I have updated my question with your query suggested. Please review my question again